# What is the antonym of 不如?

Tags: word-requests, antonyms

What is the antonym of 不如? E.g.:

> 今年我旅游很少, 不如去年 (situation is worse than last year)

And I need a word for the reverse situation:

> 今年我旅游很多, ???去年 (situation is better than last year)

不如 has a negative meaning so it does not suit here, as far as I know.

Comment: see any grammar on comparison, e。g。＂实用现代汉语语法＂，比较的方式，第一节：比较事物、形状的同异，第一节：比较性质、程度的差别、高低，第一节，一、A 跟 B 一样，二、A 有 B 那么（这么）。。。第二节：一、＂比＂字句，二、＂不比＂句，三、＂没有＂句，四、＂不如＂句。It seems the most common way would be ＂比＂字句:  **（今年）比去年好** ，may place ＂更＂、＂还＂、＂还要＂before predicate (好 in present case), also 用程度补语＂多＂表示比较的双方差别很大。例如：这只鸭子比那只肥得多。 **（今年）比去年好得多**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 超过 or 胜过(more positive)

> 今年我旅游很多, 超过去年

Comment: Two more: 尤胜 and 远超, meaning 'far better'

Comment: And to specify "N-times better" - "超过去年几倍多"

Answer (score 1):

Since 很多 has a positive meaning, simply 比起 (compared to) works：

> 今年我旅遊很多，比起去年。

Comment: 比起 has neutral meaning so it could be used in both sentences. I gueass there is still something for positive case. Any way it's very useful version "..., 跟去年比起来".

Answer (score 0):

> 今年我旅游很多, 比去年还多

This year I traveled a lot, even more than (how much I did) last year.

Answer (score 0):

像 = 如 in this context.

今年我旅遊很多，**不像** 去年。